# Show another div on active tab in jQuery Tabs UI

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, show-hide

I'm wondering how to show another div when a range of tabs in jQuery UI Tabs is active.

tabs-1 contains a small amount of text, while the other tabs 2-4 contain much more text, so those tabs - when active - extend far down the page. What I'd like to do is be able to populate the sidebar with more content in #`myotherdiv` when any of the tabs 2 through 4 are active.

So if tabs-3 is active, how do I also get another div, i.e. .extradiv to show outside the `#tabs` div in the #sidebar?

Do I hook into the active state of the tab with jQuery to show the `.extradiv` in #sidebar? Some other way?

**4/26/11 answer below works**

**Basic jQuery UI tab structure**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4"></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
"short" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
"long" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
"long" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-4">
"long" content
</div>

</div>
```

**Sidebar**

```
<div id="sidebar" class="widget">

<div class="extradiv">content</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I was incorrect. ui.panel is the <div> content of the selected tab. Apologies! I voted to delete my own post...

Comment: Could you post your HTML about how you include the `.extradiv`?

Comment: Added html above. What about toggling display:none on the .extradiv rather than show/hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event handler only fires when the tab is loaded dynamically. Use the `show` event instead:

```
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        show: function (event, ui) {
            var height = $(ui.panel).height();
            if (height > 200) {
                $('#sidebar .extradiv').show();
            } else {
                $('#sidebar .extradiv').hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @songdogtech This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eW3Jy/) seems to work fine in ie9 and FF 3.6. How is your situation different?

Comment: Thanks, it works at jsfiddle and you've got the right answer. I'm just not seeing something different in my own CSS. One small change above in the question from  `<div id="sidebar">` to `<div id="sidebar" class="widget">`. How much of a difference will that make, if any?

Comment: @songdogtech Adding class="widget" shouldn't make any difference. My fiddle keeps working when I add it. I suspect that your extradiv is hidden behind something else or has zero width and/or height. What does firebug or F12-developer tools tell you?

Comment: The key to make it work is the extra call above the main function that William shows below: `$('#sidebar .extradiv').hide();` But you were earlier with the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fred's suggestion seems to work. You might mis-configured your css? See the demo here: http://jsbin.com/ateru6/5

You can look at the source here: http://jsbin.com/ateru6/5/edit

JavaScript:

```
$('#sidebar .extradiv').hide();

$tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
  show: function(event,ui) {
        var height = $(ui.panel).height();
        $('#tabHeight').html(height);
        if (height > 200) {
           $('#sidebar .extradiv').show();
        }
        else {
           $('#sidebar .extradiv').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
  #tabs
  {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 6em;
  }

  #sidebar
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    width: 5em;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  #sidebar .extradiv
  {
    color: blue;
  }

  #tabHeight
  {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
```

Comment: I can't get this to work on a div class="extradiv" that is outside of the #tabs div, i.e. within #sidebar. And: should it toggle display:none rather than show/hide?

Comment: If you look at the code carefully, `div.extradiv` *is* outside of `#tabs` and inside `#sidebar`. Show/hide functions do toggle display:none.

Comment: Don't know what I was doing wrong on my end, but now it works. @Fred's answer needs the extra call that you include, `$('#sidebar .extradiv').hide();` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `load` event handler and check which tab is being loaded (or the size of the tab) if you want to make it more dynamic.  Add the extra content when that tab is chosen or the tab size exceeds a certain threshold.   See the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) on the jQuery UI site for more examples of how to add event handlers for the Tab widget.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    ...
    load: function(event,ui) {
        var height = $(ui.panel).height();
        if (height > _some_fixed_height) {
           $('.sidebar .extra_content').show();
        }
        else {
           $('.sidebar .extra_content').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Content height is a better idea than depending on the active tab. What kind of value do I use for _some_fixed_height? Pixels? Thanks.

Comment: @songdogtech -- yes, `height` returns the value in pixels: http://api.jquery.com/height

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with my attempt, with or without the 1000 in (); I added code above. - Mark

Answer (score 0):

This works:

try and see the red div when you go on tab 3

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln4L7/2/